# Replace multiple characters of a string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I have a column called *Review Text* with details like:

```
Review text
i\'m glad i did bc i never would have ordered it/'s
```

I wrote the following code to replace all the contractions and backslashes (`\`) with empty space and applied it using a lambda function. But when I again look at my string, I see some forward slash as well and now I can't figure out how to add it inside the replace method because it is not able to take multiple arguments.

```
def expanded(x):
    if type(x) is str:
        x = x.replace('\\', '')
        for key in contractions:
            value = contractions[key]
            x = x.replace(key, value)
        return x
    else:
        return x
```

Comment: You would need to provide a bit more info but what I see, looks like it's just backslash from special characthers.

Comment: yes, and I want to replace all the forward slash with empty space just like I did with a back slash in above code...

Comment: Why don't use the same as you used above? that is using split function.

Comment: i cant put it inside x = x.replace('\\', '').. so I was wondering If there is another way to replace both back and forward slash using the same replace method.

Comment: Yes you can.... `x = x.replace('\\', '').replace("/","")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
x = x.replace('\\', '').replace("/","")
```